# How to count the number of Twitter tweets for a search term per day

Tags: search, twitter, counting

I need to find the number (not necessarily the tweets themselves) of Tweets that have been posted on a specific date for a specific search word.

So, assuming I search for "programming" and want the number of tweets for today, I'd like a simple number like "25". It would also be okay to get all the Tweets, then I could count them themselves.

But I can't seem to find a way to limit the resulting data of the twitter search api to a specific date?! Yet it must be possible, because the people from http://trendistic.indextank.com/programming/_24-hours do it too?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, colleague found the answer: just ad "since:yyyy-mm-dd until:yyyy-mm-dd" to the search query and you get only the tweets in that range.